# Get domain and/ or subsite name in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class library that implements `IHttpHandler`.

I have different servers that I deploy on.

A staging server where the site is deployed as a subsite in IIS.

e.g `www.stagingdomain.co.za/subsite`.

On live server it would be `www.liveserver.com.`

How can I get the domain or domain/subsite without having to change code for the `.dll` for each server?

Thank you.

Comment: use relative urls! or put the url in the config file...

Answer (score 0):

In the ProcessRequest handler of IHttpHandler you get the current context. `context.Request.Url` and its properties will tell you everything you need to know.